# What do these written words mean?

Tags: cipher

Can you help me understand my doctor's message?

[image: writing]

Hint:

> The image seems to be composed of written words, but they were actually typed.

Comment: Can we assume that the doctor writing in English?

Comment: [Corrected colored version.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEMlz.png)

Comment: @newzad, the doctor's message is in English and has correct grammar and spelling.  Also, it does not contain any punctuation marks.  (It is just one sentence but does not have an ending punctuation mark.)

Comment: @Sleafar, your colored version is indeed helpful.  Each colored mark corresponds to an English letter.  A warning though:  The Doctor is Known to Capitalize Some of his Words.

Comment: "Understanding what a doctor has written" is the world's ultimate puzzle. :P

Comment: With @Sleafar's coloured version, you can solve it like a cryptogram. I'm pretty sure [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7bZq.png) is the answer, but I have no idea how each letter is encoded.

Comment: @MOehm, you should post it as an answer.  The text is correct, you'll just need to take care of the capital letters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The doctor's message says:

> Take two of These and Call Me in the Morning.

How did I find it?

> In comments, Sleafar has posted a colour-encoded version of the dictor's scribblings, where the identical "words" have the same colour and all unique words are black. The OP has confirmed that each "word" corresponds to a letter. There is no punctuation and capital letters are encoded differently from their small counterparts.
>
>  With this information, the message can be decoded like a cryptogram. Fortunately, the only letter that is used in both capital and small form is T. The decoded message is:
>
>  [image: doctor's cryptogram]
>
>  It turns out that the words were written with a special font, [The Written Word](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/letterror/the-written-word/). That's why the hint says that although the words look as if they were written, they were typed. With this information, we can now see that the C and M's are also capital letters. (Strangely, the glyphs for A and T are the same. The font seems to repeat after the capital T.)

Comment: Yes, a special font was used.  (The hint gives an idea of the name of the font.)  Once you find the font, you will discover that most of the other words are also capitalized.

Comment: (Actually, half of the words are capitalized.)  This is my first question at Puzzling.  Did you find it too easy or was the difficulty acceptable?

Comment: Aha, with the help of [What the Font!](https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) I've found it now. I had tried web searches for "doctor's handwriting font" and "illegible words font" and Google's image search, but without success.

Comment: The question has been sitting here for a whole day, so it can't have been a write-in. The difficulty of puzzles is hard to judge. The aha moment here is to find out that words correspond to letters, and that was already done when I started solving it. I thought the difficulty was okay. When trying to make a puzzle difficult, it is easy to make it too obscure. This one was short, sweet and solvable.

Comment: Thanks.  Also, I didn't know that the font had similar glyphs for some different letters.  It's a good thing this didn't cause problems for the message I created.

Answer (score 1):

> I think that the message means your doctor needs a new printer or at least someone to fix the printer.

This answer is based on the hint.

Comment: Please don't downvoted just because the answer was incorrect I will delete it. I actually thought that could be an answer. This is a riddle after all. The words were typed and appeared to be smeared. The idea that a color version is easier to solve ( as stated in a comment) lead me to believe that possibly the ink would hint to a need for repair to the printer.

Comment: Your answer is clever but is not what I intended.  Note that the puzzle is tagged [tag:cipher] and not [tag:riddle].